# Where can I download ROME rss library jar?

Tags: java, rss, rome

It seems rome downloads no longer exists here (http://java.net/projects/rome/downloads). Where can I download the jar then? is it being discontinued?
Thanks,

David

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to find it here:
http://download.java.net/maven/2/rome/

Source, doc and binary.
There is also rome-fetcher if you need it ;).

Comment: The link seems not to work anymore

Answer (score 12):

You can find downloads on ROME wiki site - https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home

Direct link - [ROME 1.0 library jar](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/download/attachments/1998914/rome-1.0.jar)

**Edit:** removed link to hxxp://rometools.org. The site doesn't belongs to ROME project anymore.